# Matter.Js scaling a sprite (related to other variables)

Tags: javascript, sprite, matter.js

I'm using Matter.Js for an interactive animation. One feature I'm working on is to scale some of my bodies relative to their distance to the cursor. My issue is that I cannot seem to scale the sprite which covers these bodies. I tried scaling the bodies themselves but the sprite size did not actually change. So I figured I just needed to scale the sprite size. However I can't seem to get any configuration of `Matter.Body.set()` to make this change. Reading the source I'm not sure it is possible.

The [documentation](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_set) says: "Given a property and a value (or map of), sets the property(s) on the body, using the appropriate setter functions if they exist. Prefer to use the actual setter functions in performance critical situations."

I've tried:

```
Body.set(body, {
  render: {
    sprite: {
      texture: // url to sprite reset here incase of overwrite,
      xScale: scaleFactor,
      yScale: scaleFactor
    }
  }
});
```

This just seems to remove the sprite and any other render settings so I see nothing.

I've tried:

```
Body.set(body, 'render.sprite.xScale', scaleFactor);
```

This seems to do nothing at all and doesn't change the rendering.

Is it not possible to set the values of the sprite object at any moment other than the creation of the body? Or am I just targeting those values wrong in my function calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the scale directly on the sprite properties and scale the body by `Body.scale`:

```
body.render.sprite.xScale = box.render.sprite.xScale * scaleX;
body.render.sprite.yScale = box.render.sprite.yScale * scaleY;
Matter.Body.scale( body, scaleX, scaleY);
```

here is a toy example.

```js
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  Render = Matter.Render,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
  Body = Matter.Body;

var engine = Engine.create();

var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
width: 800,
height: 400,
wireframes: false
  }
});

engine.world.gravity.y = 0;

var box = Bodies.rectangle(460, 120, 40, 40, { render: { strokeStyle: '#ffffff',
                sprite: {
                    texture: '//cdn.rawgit.com/liabru/matter-js/2560a681/demo/img/box.png'
                }
            }
        });

World.add(engine.world, [box]);

Engine.run(engine);

Render.run(render);

$('.scale').on('click', function () {
box.render.sprite.xScale = box.render.sprite.xScale * 1.5;
box.render.sprite.yScale = box.render.sprite.yScale * 1.2;
Body.scale( box, 1.5, 1.2);
});

$('.rotate').on('click', function () {
Body.rotate( box, Math.PI/6);
});

$('.translate').on('click', function () {
Body.translate( box, {x: -10, y: 20});
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

canvas {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background: orange;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.11.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="scale">Scale</button>
<button class="rotate">Rotate</button>
<button class="translate">Translate</button>
<br>
```

Please note that sprite texture is scaled in initial coordinates (local ones), while the body (box in this case) will be scaled in rotated coordinate system if a rotation has been previously applied.

Comment: interestingly you don't even need to call `scale()` on the body if you don't want the size of the body to change

Comment: Yes, indeed. Apparently render is continuously updating after you run it.